# Replace label value by using links, similar to select tags

Tags: javascript, html, select, replace

Good day,

I'm trying to figure out a way to replace label values by using links, similar to select tags - so it replaces values after pressing a link. I've got this below, which doesn't quite work as expected:

```js
function My1() {
  let lblA = document.getElementById('My1lbl');
  let lblB = document.getElementById('My1t1');
  let lblC = document.getElementById('My1t2');
  let replaceName = document.getElementById('replaceMy1').value;
  let replaceTitle = document.getElementById('replaceMy1').title;
  lblA.innerText = replaceName;
  lblB.innerText = replaceTitle;
  lblC.innerText = replaceTitle;
}

function My2() {
  let lblA = document.getElementById('My2lbl');
  let lblB = document.getElementById('My2t1');
  let lblC = document.getElementById('My2t2');
  let replaceName = document.getElementById('replaceMy2').value;
  let replaceTitle = document.getElementById('replaceMy2').title;
  lblA.innerText = replaceName;
  lblB.innerText = replaceTitle;
  lblC.innerText = replaceTitle;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:My1()">Title 1<input id="replaceMy1" title="Title 1" value="1st Value" style="display: none"></a>
<a href="javascript:My2()">Title 2<input id="replaceMy2" title="Title 2" value="2nd Value" style="display: none"></a>

<span id="My1t1"><span id="My2t1">yet not replaced Title A</span></span>
<span id="My1t2"><span id="My2t2">yet not replaced Title B</span></span>
<label id="My1lbl"><label id="My2lbl">yet not replaced Value</label></label>
```

*Somehow the snippet doesn't work here, so here is the same code (working) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjBPax).*

It's great if you have only one function like this, but if you have two or more it junks your JS file and the main downside is, that it works only after the first click - if you want to go back to a value replaced before, the links don't work.

Basically I want to achieve the functionalities like here, but just with links instead of select/option tags: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBbmqX.

Any ideas how to overcome this challenge?

Comment: `if you want to go back to a value replaced before` - How are you planning to do this? In fact what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the identical possibilities like here, but just with links instead of select/option tags: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBbmqX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need only 1 function which will take input `an identifier` for the element that is clicked and retrieve data corresponding to it and populate accordingly. Also, remove unnecessary `span` and `label` inside `span` and `label`, respectively.

Try following

```js
function My(id) {
  // Get the elements that needs to be updated
  let lblA = document.getElementById('My1lbl');
  let lblB = document.getElementById('My1t1');
  let lblC = document.getElementById('My1t2');
 
  // Get the corresponding values
  let replaceName = document.getElementById('replaceMy' + id).value;
  let replaceTitle = document.getElementById('replaceMy' + id).title;

  // Update the element text
  lblA.innerText = replaceName;
  lblB.innerText = replaceTitle;
  lblC.innerText = replaceTitle;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:My(1)">Title 1<input id="replaceMy1" title="Title 1" value="1st Value" style="display: none"></a>
<a href="javascript:My(2)">Title 2<input id="replaceMy2" title="Title 2" value="2nd Value" style="display: none"></a>

<span id="My1t1">yet not replaced Title A</span>
<span id="My1t2">yet not replaced Title B</span>
<label id="My1lbl">yet not replaced Value</label>
```

Comment: @512SonnyBurnett - Glad to help you :)

Comment: Additional question if I may ask: is there a way to define an <embed> tag as value? Because when I do this, after clicking the link it shows just the HTML code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLoQrK

Comment: @512SonnyBurnett - As you are trying to add some html, use `innerHTML` in place of `innerText`

Comment: The solutions always seem to be so easy, I wonder if someday I will get to them on my own. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there also a way to add additional span, which would create a link depending on the choice? So for example that if someone chooses the first link, it would place a link like this in a span tag: <a target="_blank" href="C:\Users\User name\Desktop\Title 1">Title 1</a>

The 'Title 1', 'Title 2' etc. would obviously be folders on the desktop.

Comment: @512SonnyBurnett - yes you can do that. In that case you will need to change the `href`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't get it working. I know I'm doing something wrong with the `let replaceLink` attribute: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLZEwr

Comment: Check this out - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjmXwy . You need to use `replaceTitle` in place of `title`, `innerHTML` in place of `innerText` and escape slashes

Comment: Oh, was not that far away from the solution, but you made it stick again! Thank you for all the goods, again